# Selenium Webdriver not able to locate and click button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create a scraper, and for accessing the page I need to click on the Accept Cookies button.
The HTML referring to the button is:

```
<div class="qc-cmp2-summary-buttons">
    <button mode="secondary" size="large" class=" css-1hy2vtq">
        <span>MORE OPTIONS</span>
    </button><button mode="primary" size="large" class=" css-47sehv">
        <span>AGREE</span></button></div>
```

The button I want to click is the second one, named "AGREE".

I tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, " css-47sehv").click()
```

and I get error
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: If the button is on a popup window, then you first need to find the window, often an iframe, then move focus to it `driver.switch_to.frame(frame)`, and then look for the button and click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you received caused by a space   before the class name value.
Spaces between class names are used to separate between multiple class names.
So, to use this specific class name you could try this (without the space):

```py
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-47sehv").click()
```

But `css-47sehv` seems to be a dynamically generated class name so I'd advice to use more fixed attribute for locating that element.
Try this locator instead:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'AGREE')]").click()
```

To give you better answer we need to see that web page and all your Selenium code

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed the white space was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use By.CSS_SELECTOR. Find element and copy its selector

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).